# Limiting player rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can rotate player by clicking on left or right arrows but i want to make player Z rotation limited between -85 and 85, how can i do that?
this is the code:

```
void Start()
    {
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
     void Update () 
     {
         InputX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
         
     }

  void FixedUpdate()
    {
        
        body.velocity = -transform.up*speed;

         if(InputX != 0)
         {  
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * InputX);
         }
 
        
    }
```

Comment: Note that in general when dealing with a Rigidbody you shouldn't rotate by using the `transform` component **at all**! This breaks the physics and collision detection. Rather use [`body.MoveRotation(targetRotation);`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html) instead

Comment: Could show me how can i make targetRotation depend on InputX!